# C#.net bitwise shift left operation.?

Tags: c#

```
var x = 2;
var y=x+2<<2;
Console.WriteLine(y);
output = 16
```

my doubt is that how 16 is come.i know about bitwise shift left operator.what kind of operation is done.

Comment: Which bit are you struggling with? its basically (2+2) * 4

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention to operator precedence. `2 + 2 << 2` is *not* `2 + (2 << 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

its same as below :-

```
x + 2 = 4;

4 << 2 ////it means 16 if you perform bitwise on this.
```

Desciption to understand Let shift operation :-

> Shifts bits to the left. The number to the left of the operator is
>   shifted the number of places specified by the number to the right.
>   Each shift to the left doubles the number, therefore each left shift
>   multiplies the original number by 2. Use the left shift for fast
>   multiplication or to pack a group of numbers together into one larger
>   number. Left shifting only works with integers or numbers which
>   automatically convert to an integer such at byte and char.

so in your case lets say presentation for 4 is `100` and it would be shifted by `2` so it becomes `10000` which is presentation of `16` :-

```
for 4 :- 100
left shift by 2 so,
10000 ////Which is 16
```